# My MacBookPro with Windows takes too long to establish a WiFi connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, macbook-pro

Whenever I close the laptop and then open it, Windows comes up immediately, but the WiFi connection is not established for a well over 45 seconds.

All other devices (including another Windows laptop, iPad, iPod, etc...) connect immediately.
What could be the issue?

My MacBookPro is about 2 years old.

Comment: @Karan That did the trick.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, and I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the network adapter's properties in **Device Manager**, and on the **Power Management** tab disable the option to turn off the device to save power:

[image: 1]